# Check std::string whether contains any lowercase character?

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/char_encoding/ascii.hpp>

bool IsStringAllNonLowercaseA(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string newStr(str);

    boost::to_upper(newStr);

    if (newStr == str)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool IsStringAllNonLowercaseB(const std::string& str)
{
    for (std::string::const_iterator iter=str.begin(); iter != str.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii::islower(*iter))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Question**> I am looking for an efficient way to check whether a `std::string` contains all uppercase. It will be best if there is a standard function from C++ standard or boost library.

I have implemented two versions of it myself. But I am not sure whether they are good enough. Any suggestion and comments are welcome.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please define what "good enough" means. By what criteria do you plan to select the "best" answer from the answers you get here? Please also note that detecting any lowercase characters (as the title requests) is not the same as detecting whether the characters are all uppercase (as the body requests). Punctuation, Far East characters, symbols, and digits are usually neither.

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a predefined function that can tell me whether or not a string contains any lowercase. Your point is valid and I have changed my function name in OP.

Comment: -1. The function *names* were only *one* source of inconsistency. Either way, at least one function doesn't do what its name says it does. **First**, get your requirements clear. **Then** worry about speed.

Answer (score 7):

My initial reaction would probably be something like this:

```
return std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::islower) == str.end();
```

If you have C++ 11 available, you could also use:

```
return !std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::islower);
```

Edit: As James Kanze pointed out, either/both of these can/will have undefined behavior given the wrong input (where "wrong" means almost anything outside the basic ASCII characters required in the basic execution character set). To correct it, the values need to be cast to unsigned char before being passed to ::isupper.

```
struct IsUpper {
    bool operator()(int value) {
        return ::isupper((unsigned char)value); 
    }
};

return std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), IsUpper()) == str.end();
```

or:

```
return !std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), IsUpper());
```

Alternatively, you could use a lambda:

```
return std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
    [](int ch) { return ::isupper(unsigned char)ch);}) == str.end();
```

or:

```
return !std:any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), 
    [](char ch) { return ::isupper(unsigned char)ch)); });
```

Comment: I'd also tend to use `std::find_if`.  But I'd check against the end iterator, and not `std::string::npos`:-).

Comment: And now that I think about it, I'd also use the functional object I posted earlier.  `::islower` has undefined behavior when called with a `char` as argument (at least if plain `char` is signed).

Comment: @James : What UB are you referring to?

Comment: @ildjarn: If you pass a negative value (other than EOF) to isupper, islower, etc., you get UB.

Comment: @ildjarn, the ctype family of functions take an `int`, if it happens to be negative on some implementations this will crash. Since `char` is signed in many implementations, things in the non-ascii range (> 128) are considered negative.

Comment: @Evan, Jerry : Thanks; I always use the function templates from `<locale>` so I wasn't aware of this particular pitfall.

Comment: @ildjarn: yea, some people recommend something like this: `template <int (&F) (int)> int safe_ctype (unsigned char c) { return F(c); }` which would be used like `int x = safe_ctype<std::isspace>(ch)`. And doesn't crash on negative values.

Comment: @EvanTeran It's undefined behavior, as far as the standard is concerned,
but I've never seen it crash.  At least one implementation (Sun CC), and
probably others, make it work as far as possible, but they still give
wrong results for `'ÿ'` (which is code 255 in Latin 1).  And of course,
if the input is UTF-8 (as it often is these days), the functions don't
work at all (but then, a lot of other things don't either).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I know it's UB. That was kinda the point of my comment. I was just giving an example of one way the the functions can behave if given negative input. I've seen many implementations which crash (namely every one which uses a lookup table for the ctype functions..)

Comment: Why was your original answer using ::islower then in your edit you switched to using ::isupper?

Comment: @Jon: I don't remember for sure. Probably from rereading the question: the "headline" asks about lower-case, but the body asks about anything other than upper-case. Affects how you react if you find (for example) a digit.